# Processing my form with required fields php

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I'm just starting to learn php, so I suspect this is going to be an easy one. I want to create a form that has one required field (name) and requires at least one of two other fields (email or phone number). This is what I came up with:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    if (empty($_POST["name"]) or {empty($_POST["email"]) and empty($_POST["number"])}) {     
            $error = "Your name and a contact method are required fields";}

    else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $number = $_POST["number"];
        $contactmethod = $_POST["contactmethod"];
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $location = $_POST["location"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $subjectline = "You have a message from $name!";
        $header = "From: $email";

$body = <<<EMAIL

Name: $name,
Number: $number, 
Email: $email, 
Subject: $subject,
Location: $location,
Contact method: $contactmethod.

$message

EMAIL;

mail("MYEMAILADDRESS", $subjectline, $body, $header);
}
} 
?>
```

I have no clue what's wrong.

Thanks

Comment: "I have no clue what's wrong." nor does any one else, as you have yet to explain the issue

Comment: ok you have 2 curly brackets that should be regular ones, I'll let you find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem: You used { and } in a if-statement.

Next time you can use a PHP code checker like http://phpcodechecker.com/

Correct code:

```
    if (empty($_POST["name"]) or (empty($_POST["email"]) and empty($_POST["number"]))) {     
            $error = "Your name and a contact method are required fields";}

    else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $number = $_POST["number"];
        $contactmethod = $_POST["contactmethod"];
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $location = $_POST["location"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $subjectline = "You have a message from $name!";
        $header = "From: $email";

$body = <<<EMAIL

Name: $name,
Number: $number, 
Email: $email, 
Subject: $subject,
Location: $location,
Contact method: $contactmethod.

$message

EMAIL;

mail("MYEMAILADDRESS", $subjectline, $body, $header);
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: Hm... I thought I say that the braces should be used in such a situation... I guess not. Thanks for that. My webpage is loading fine now, though it's still not emailing me so something else is wrong too. Thanks for telling me about http://phpcodechecker.com/.

Comment: Do you have your own webserver or did you hired one?

Comment: I'm seeing. What is $body = <<<EMAIL and EMAIL;? I don't know this commands? And did you configured your php processor with your mailserver?

Comment: I'm paying GoDaddy to host my site. No, I didn't configure my php processor with my mail server; I believe that part is automatic on the GoDaddy server. (However, it might be a good idea to figure out how to get MAMP to email me.) I was able to get everything to work once you guys helped me with the above problem. It was a silly labeling issue between the form I was using the my php code. It wasn't too hard to figure everything out after I stopped getting a blank page.

Comment: Try defining a string at the $body var. Check this site out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: No problem. One question: Do you want send plain text mails or use HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use braces interchangeably with parentheses.

```
if (empty($_POST["name"]) or {empty($_POST["email"]) and empty($_POST["number"])}) {
```

it needs to use parentheses

```
if (empty($_POST["name"]) or (empty($_POST["email"]) and empty($_POST["number"]))) {
```